# Software to download audio playing on a website

Tags: download-manager, audiobook

The following link: https://www.audiobookcup.com/bigger-leaner-stronger-audiobook/
has audio that can be played on the website. Is there any tool that can be used to download this?

Comment: "Audiobook Cup is a free audio book listening platform. You can listen to thousands of audiobooks online for free on this site, or you can download audiobooks offline by paying $ 4.99." - I'm not sure whether we help in finding tools for illegal activities.

Comment: I am glad that I saw your comment before posting an answer :-)  Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

In general if a webpage does not prevent this, you can download media with browser extensions, such as [flashgot](https://flashgot.net) for firefox or [bulk media downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/bulk-media-downloader) for chrome.

Understandably Audiobook Cup does not allow you to do this.